# Maxima and minima second derivative

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f(x) = 2x^{3} - x^{4} - 10$ over $[-1,1]$

I found second derivative as $12x - 12x^2$

After trying values I found that  $f(x)$ gives minimum value at $x=-1$

If I substitute $x=-1$ in second derivative, then I get $-24<0$ so it should be Maxima right 
Should we check second derivative only for critical points ? If yes, then why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = 2x^3 - x^4 - 10 $$
It is defined, continuous, and differentiable at every point in $[-1,1]$

$$f'(x)=6x^2-4x^3$$
$$f''(x)=12x-12x^2$$

Let $f'(x)=0$, we find $x=0, \frac{3}{2}$

For $x \in [-1,1]$, we exclude $x=\frac{3}{2}$.

$f''(0)=0$, thus we cannot directly tell if it is max or min. or neither.

Thus we now complete value at $0$ and at boundaries:

$$f(0)=-10, \, f(1)=-9, \,f(-1)=-13$$

Thus max=$-9$, and min=$-13$

Or even better, we could see that:
$$f'(x)=6x^2-4x^3 \ge 0 \text{ over }[-1,1]$$

Thus it is non-decreasing over $[-1,1]$, and we get the result immediately

Comment: Even I have solved the same. But I want to know why the condition of f''(x) <0 for Maxima is only for critical points and not boundary points

Comment: @Zephyr So first of all, you do not need to check for second derivatives for this particular case (see my last section of the answer); and for your question in the comment: we want to use second derivative to check if points of $\{x: \,f'(x)=0\}$ is local max, local min, or neither.

Comment: @Zephyr But global max/min does not always happen at where first derivative equals to zero, but could also happens, for example, at where first derivative does not exists, at boundary, at infinity, etc. And for those points, they are not local max/min candidates, and thus second derivative check is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: $f''(x_0)<0$ implies $f(x)$ is concave at the point $x_0$. If $x_0$ is a critical point ($f'(x_0)=0$), then it is a relative maximum. In your case $-1$ is not a critical point (it is a border point). Your problem is called a constrained optimization problem. According to the Extreme value theorem, the function is continuous in a closed interval, so it must have max and min. Now its extreme (max/min) values will be at either critical or border points, which is what you calculated. In general, the relative max could be not max of a constrained optimization problem. For example: find max of $f(x)=x^3-3x$ in $[-3,3]$.